# How is it possible that the language a^n b^2n is regular if and only if it was finite such that 100 => n <= 0?

Tags: regular-language, automata, language-theory, automata-theory

how is it possible that the language a^n b^2n is regular if and only if it was finite such that 100 => n <= 0?

I know that a language in such a form of ( a^n b^n ) when n=>0 is not regular, since we need a temporary memory to keep track of the number of a's and b's, and I know every *finite* language is regular, but I do not understand what make a finite language in a similar form regular? how can we proof it? I need some clue, besides being able to get its equivalent regular expression, I want some more detailed explanation..

Thanx

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is is not about programming; try http://cs.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: You know that every finite language is regular and this language is finite. What else do you need?

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to think about building a regular expression for the language:

> ε ∪ abb ∪ aabbbb ∪ aaabbbbbb ∪ ... ∪ a<sup>100</sup>b<sup>200</sup>.

You're right that all finite languages are regular, and since this particular language is finite, it's regular.

Note that it's *not* the case that this language is regular if and only if you restrict n such that 0 ≤ n ≤ 100. Rather, the language formed by adding in the restriction that 0 ≤ n ≤ 100 is regular. There are other things you can do to restrict the language so that it's regular - for example, you could use an upper bound of 1,000 or 100,000.